# Swap elements of two structures

Tags: c, pointers, struct, call-by-value

I have simplified my question to this small C program. Please note that I am learning C on my own. I a having real trouble with pointers!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Elmt_ {
    int *i;
    struct Elmt_ *next;
} E;

void swap_1(E *x, E *y) {
    int *temp = NULL;
    temp = x->i;
    x->i = y->i;
    y->i = temp;
}

void swap_2(E *x, E *y) {
    int *temp=NULL;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *temp = *(x->i);
    *(x->i) = *(y->i);
    *(y->i) = *temp;
}

int main() {
    E *p, *q, *r, *s;

    int a, b;
    a = 8;
    b = 50;

    p = malloc(sizeof(E));
    q = malloc(sizeof(E));
    p->i = &a;
    p->next = NULL;

    q->i = &b;
    q->next = NULL;
    printf("Initially, *(p->i)=%d *(q->i)=%d\n", *(p->i), *(q->i));
    swap_1(p,q);
    printf("After swap_1, *(p->i)=%d *(q->i)=%d\n", *(p->i), *(q->i));

    r = malloc(sizeof(E));
    s = malloc(sizeof(E));
    r->i = &a;
    s->i = &b;
    printf("Initially, *(r->i)=%d *(s->i)=%d\n", *(r->i), *(s->i));
    swap_2(r,s);
    printf("After swap_2, *(r->i)=%d *(s->i)=%d\n", *(r->i), *(s->i));
    return 0;
}
```

**Question:**In the above program, is `swap_1` or the `swap_2` the right way to swap the integer value pointed to by `i` ?

I see that both these functions seem to swap the values given as arguments correctly.

```
$ ./a.out
Initially, *(p->i)=8 *(q->i)=50
After swap_1, *(p->i)=50 *(q->i)=8

Initially, *(r->i)=8 *(s->i)=50
After swap_2, *(r->i)=50 *(s->i)=8
```

Comment: You posted almost this exact same question yesterday, and then deleted it to repost it again. Never do that, people will figure it out and punish you for it. If you're not satisfied with the response gotten to your question, *edit* it to improve it. And take some time to actually read posted comments and (possible) answers. Reply to comments or answers if you want clarification.

Comment: Also refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And please retake the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 2):

Function `swap_1` swaps the pointer values, not the pointed values.

Function `swap_2` swaps the pointed values, but yields a memory leak.

In order to swap the pointed values cleanly, you can simply do:

```
void swap_3(E *x, E *y) {
    int temp;
    temp = *(x->i);
    *(x->i) = *(y->i);
    *(y->i) = temp;
}
```

Comment: No need to separate declare and initialize `temp`.

Comment: @Chris: Of course, but I tried to keep it as close as possible to his/her original code, in order to reduce any possible confusion to a minimum (i.e., keep the focus on the actual changes, and not on unrelated semantic changes).

Comment: Of course. That might be suited to an addendum at the end of the answer on code style. Similarly, due to the associativity of the deref operator, `*x->i` will suit where `*(x->i)` is used.

Comment: Thank you @bbbbbbbbb. I am just learning C and want to understand two more points: (1) what causes memory leak in my swap_2 function? and (2) is it acceptable to use the swap_1 function as well since it swaps the addresses of the element 'i' in r and s structs? Thanks again for being so kind to take time to help me understand and learn better.

Comment: @noobee `malloc` without a matching `free` is what causes the leak,

Answer (score 1):

Lets take the `swap_1` function:

```
void swap_1(E *x, E *y) {
    int *temp = NULL;
    temp = x->i;
    x->i = y->i;
    y->i = temp;
}
```

And *draw* each and every step to see what happens.

- Lets begin with

  ```
  int *temp = NULL;
  ```

  and look at all the pointers you have and where they point, then it would look something like this:

  ```
  +------+
  | temp | --> NULL
  +------+

  +---+     +---+     +-------------+
  | x | --> | i | --> | a from main |
  +---+     +---+     +-------------+

  +---+     +---+     +-------------+
  | y | --> | i | --> | b from main |
  +---+     +---+     +-------------+
  ```
- Now lets do our first assignment:

  ```
  temp = x->i;
  ```

  And look and how it changes things:

  ```
  +------+
  | temp | ----------\
  +------+           |    +-------------+
                     >--> | a from main |
  +---+     +---+    |    +-------------+
  | x | --> | i | --/
  +---+     +---+ 

  +---+     +---+     +-------------+
  | y | --> | i | --> | b from main |
  +---+     +---+     +-------------+
  ```

  As you can see you now have two pointers, both pointing to the same location (the `a` variable from the `main` function).
- Now lets do the second assignment:

  ```
  x->i = y->i;
  ```

  Which will change things like this:

  ```
  +------+     +-------------+
  | temp | --> | a from main |
  +------+     +-------------+

  +---+     +---+
  | x | --> | i | --\ 
  +---+     +---+   |    +-------------+
                    >--> | b from main |
  +---+     +---+   |    +-------------+
  | y | --> | i | --/
  +---+     +---+
  ```

  Again you have two pointers both pointing to the same location (both `x->i` and `y->i` are pointing to the variable `b` from the `main` function).
- And lastly the last assignment:

  ```
  y->i = temp;
  ```

  After this assignment the pointers will look like this:

  ```
  +---+     +---+     +-------------+
  | x | --> | i | --> | b from main |
  +---+     +---+     +-------------+

  +------+
  | temp | ----------\
  +------+           |    +-------------+
                     >--> | a from main |
  +---+     +---+    |    +-------------+
  | y | --> | i | --/
  +---+     +---+
  ```

From this it's clear that the `swap_1` function doesn't swap the *values* of the `a` and `b` variables from the `main` function. Instead it swaps the *pointers* `x->i` and `y->i`. The values of `a` and `b` will still be the same.

To swap the actual values of `a` and `b` you need to dereference the pointers and use a plain non-pointer type for `temp`:

```
void swap_1(E *x, E *y)
{
    int temp = *x->i;  // Copy the value from where x->i points
    *x->i = *y->i;     // Copy the value
    *y->i = temp;      // Copy the value again
}
```

---

If you have problems with pointers in the future, using pencil and paper to draw and redraw variables and the pointers similar to the above usually helps visualize what's really happening. I suggest you try it yourself.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. Really appreciate it. One last question I have: if I just want to swap the addresses stored in x->i and y->i (but not the integer values stored in a and b), then is my swap_1 function an acceptable way to do this? The idea I am getting to is that if I just swap the addresses of x->i and y->i, then I can use *(x->i) and *(y->i) to access the values without actually changing the values of a and b.

Comment: @noobee If you just want to swap the pointer `x->i` with `y->i` then yes your current `swap_1` function will work for that.

Comment: Thank you all for helping understand this better. Drawing the pointer diagrams and using pointer addresses on these diagrams immensely helped. I understand pointer usage much better now. Really appreciate all the help from all of you.